# How to extrude only edges

Tags: edges, extrude, select

I wished to extrude edges of a plane to create opened box. I have created a plane, switched to edit mode, switched to edge select, then started shift selecting edges. I can select 1, 2 or 3 edges normally, but once I select 4th edge, entire face is selected automatically.

[image]

Consequently, I can't exctrude edges, entire face is extruded.

Why and how to overcome?

https://youtu.be/fEuzIabBYLo

Comment: That's the way it works, it will select the face, so maybe extrude and delete the face afterwards?

Comment: Generally if you select all the geometry which holds a face, that face also gets selected. If you want to extrude only edges, try to use Extrude edges command (Alt+E) instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I wish users were a bit more curious and explored the menus...)

The Extrude function will extrude a face.

If you olny want to extrude the edges, select the face, then use Edge> **Extrude Edges**.

[image]

Likewise, if you want to extrude only vertices, then use Vertex > **Extrude Vertices**

[image]

Comment: Cool :). To be honest I totally missed this function when trying to answer this...

Answer (score 0):

Add a cube, go to *Edit Mode* and in *Face Selection Mode* (press <kbd>3</kbd>), then delete the upper face.